# C# MVC3 storing MetaData in a single class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to store the metadata information of 2 models in a single class?

For example I'm working on Login and Registration model, both has username and password. Usually we create another class that will contain the meta data information: LoginMetadata and RegistrationMetadata. Or put the metadata information in the Login and Registration class.

What I want to do is to create a single UserMetadata class then store the combined metadata information from Login and Registration model in it. In this case I have a single validation rule for username, password, etc. Is that possible?

Regards,
czetsuya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not possible to store metadata for multiple classes in one class.

The `MetaDataTypeAttribute` is decorated with `[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]`, so it can only be used on classes and can only be used once. It means that you cannot not define a class as a metadata placeholder for multiple classes.

Link to [MSDN Documentation for MetaDataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the verification I was hoping that I can create a generic metadata class for a single entity that can be reuse.